# Can Cilium-Istio be deployed using the Istio operator?

Tags: kubernetes, operator-keyword, istio, cilium

We are moving to Cilium as our Kubernetes CNI plugin. We also use the Istio service mesh, and would like to bring Cilium's benefits to our Istio deployment. I understand that in order to do so, we would need to deploy Cilium's "instrumented" version of Istio (https://github.com/cilium/istio). Cilium provides a version of the istioctl CLI that deploys Cilium's version of Istio. However, we deploy/maintain Istio in our clusters using the Istio Operator. The cilium-istioctl CLI seems to install the upstream Istio Operator, which then installs upstream Istio, not the Cilium version of it. Is there a Cilium version of the Istio Operator?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just swap the images out in your operator manifest. This note is from the latest cilium-istio release, noting that all they do is swap proxy and pilot with cilium's images, everything else is default.

https://github.com/cilium/istio/releases/tag/1.9.6

```
Istioctl with defaults to cilium images of proxy and pilot, 
other images default to upstream Istio, tag 1.9.6.
```

Comment: FYI: see the official website for the current version. Google "cilium istio". The URL has the version embedded in it.